# Using FTRACE to debug software hang

Tags: android, linux-kernel, ftrace

How do you use FTRACE to debug software hang issue?  I assume we can't even type anything on the busybox shell after software hangs. Is there any way it can save the traces into sdcard or something?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by hang? do you see a kernel-panic? There exists an option to automatically dump to a file on a kernel-panic . Add `ftrace=function ftrace_dump_on_oops` to the kernel cmd-line during boot.

Comment: Thanks. Hang means if there is chip or hardware issue, sometimes software can just hang. No kernel panic. Just froze. Trying to trace where the last few calls were. Maybe it tried to access bad registers or ...